# Encrypting a Large File of irregular size using AES algorithm

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes

Currently in my project, i am required to encrypt a large file of variable size (around 1 to 1.5 GB)

I am using the aes algorithm from the openssl project. But i am not using the entire library, but just a few functions which generate keys from "passwords" and use those keys to encrypt a fixed block of 128 bytes

In short,

```
void aes_encrypt(char* in, char* out , AES_KEY ekey);
void aes_decrypt(char* in, char* out , AES_KEY dkey);
```

The main problem now is that these functions work with a block size of 128 bytes only.

So i must write a wrapper function which takes my file and divides it into chunks of 128 bytes, and feed it to these encryption/decryption routines.

So my question is,

- In my wrapper, how do i handle the case where the file size is not an
  integer multiple of 128
- Do i need to pad the encrypted file with 0's to make a multiple of
- If this is the case, how do i recognize the amount zero padding i have done, as i understand that just removing the last bits of 0
  from a file, may result in the file losing integrity especially if
  the file happens to contain a 0 at the end.
- Is it a better approach to prepend a header to the encrypted file,
  containing the size information of the file and possibly its
  checksum.

Thanks.

ps: I am new to encryption(especially AES)

Comment: Unless this is about learning AES, you should really be using the `EVP_` higher level functions. If you cannot (because of an extremely limited runtime?) you can always try and replicate the behavior of the `EVP_` functionality. Especially if you otherwise just use AES without having a clue how to perform cryptography in the first place - even `EVP_` won't protect you from ideas such as "...in the file loosing integrity...".

Comment: Thanks, i'll definitely use EVP_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block length is 128 bit or 16 bytes. You can for example use PKCS7 padding (see section 10.3 of [RFC 2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315)) to make the last block 16 bytes long.

It works like this: if one byte needs to be added you add a byte with value (all values shown in hex) `01`, if two bytes need to be added you add two bytes with values `02`, and so on. In the case that no padding is required you still have to add a block with 16 padding bytes with value `10`.

To remove the padding bytes, just look at the last byte of the file, it gives the number of bytes to remove.

Also note that ECB mode (encrypting blocks independently of each other) is probably not the best to use, have a look at CBC mode as well.

Comment: Your 10 is really 16, isn't it? You should prefix with 0x or use 16 decimal to be clear.

Comment: @jim-flood Even in context of *byte* values with *2-digit* format? Are you serious?

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Yes I was, I was serious, wasn't I? It's both a blessing and a curse. :^)

Comment: @AntonSamsonov if we write our answers to be read by experienced & competent programmers, we will for sure have to answer 0b10 times as many questions.